# manage.py runserver invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**Update**

I had unintentionally edited the manage.py file.

The code in the manage.py file needs to be -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project1.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then in CMD (Windows Key + R) I put -

```
C:\Users\HP\django_project1\django_project1>cd C:\Users\HP\django_project1
```

**Original Question**
I am trying to run the command `python manage.py runserver`, `$python manage.py runserver` and `$ python manage.py runserver` but keep getting errors.

I have tried `python manage.py runserver`,`manage.py runserver` and `python3 manage.py runserver`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HP>cd C:\Users\HP

C:\Users\HP>cd C:Users\HP\django_project
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\HP>cd C:\Users\HP\django_project

C:\Users\HP\django_project>python manage.py runserver
  File "manage.py", line 3
    python3 manage.py runserver
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Users\HP\django_project>manage.py runserver
  File "C:\Users\HP\django_project\manage.py", line 3
    python3 manage.py runserver
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Users\HP\django_project>python3 manage.py runserver
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\HP\django_project>python manage.py runserver
  File "manage.py", line 3
    python3 manage.py runserver
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


C:\Users\HP\django_project>dir /s >listmyfolder.txt



 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is D84A-5EE6

 Directory of C:\Users\HP\django_project

10/20/2019  10:15 PM    <DIR>          .
10/20/2019  10:15 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/19/2019  05:50 PM    <DIR>          django_project
10/20/2019  10:15 PM               113 listmyfolder.txt
10/20/2019  08:23 PM                53 manage.py
               2 File(s)            166 bytes
```

Here is the contents of django_project -

```
 Directory of C:\Users\HP\django_project\django_project

10/19/2019  05:50 PM    <DIR>          .
10/19/2019  05:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/19/2019  05:50 PM             3,232 settings.py
10/19/2019  05:50 PM               777 urls.py
10/19/2019  05:50 PM               421 wsgi.py
10/19/2019  05:50 PM                 0 __init__.py
               4 File(s)          4,430 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               6 File(s)          4,596 bytes
               5 Dir(s)   7,345,328,128 bytes free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you appear to have edited your manage.py file so that it contains the text "python3 manage.py runserver". I don't know why you did that, but you should delete it.

Comment: Thank you, I was inexperienced with Sublime and made the change without meaning to.